# How to delete a large node in firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a Firebase child node with about 15,000,000 child objects with a total size of about 8 GB of data.

exampele data structure:

```
firebase.com/childNode/$pushKey

each $pushKey contains a small flat dictionary: 
{a: 1.0, b: 2.0, c: 3.0}
```

**I would like to delete this data as efficiently and easy as possible. How?**

What i Tried: 
My first try was a put request:

```
PUT firebase.com/childNode.json?auth=FIRE_SECRET
data-raw: null
```

> response: {
>       "error": "Data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request.  Contact support@firebase.com for help."
>   }

So that didn't work, let's do a limit request:

```
PUT firebase.com/childNode.json?auth=FIRE_SECRET&orderBy="$key"&limitToFirst=100
data-raw: null
```

> response: {
>       "error": "Querying related parameters not supported on this request type"
>   }

No luck so far :( What about writing a script that will get the first X number of keys and then create a patch request with each value set to null?

```
GET firebase.com/childNode.json?auth=FIRE_SECRET&shallow=true&orderBy="$key"&limitToLast=100
```

> {
>     "error" : "Mixing 'shallow' and querying parameters is not supported"
>   }

It's really not going to be easy this one? I could remove the shallow requirement and get the keys, and finish the script. I was just hoping there would be a easier/more efficient way???

Another thing i tried were to create a node script that listen for childAdded and then directly tries to remove those children?

```
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {console.log("Login Failed!", error)}
  if (!error) {console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData)}

  ref.child("childNode").on("child_added", function(snap) {
    console.log(`found: ${snap.key()}`)
    ref.child("childNode").child(snap.key()).remove( function(err) {
      if (!err) {console.log(`deleted: ${snap.key()}`)}
    })
  })
})
```

This script actually hangs right now, but earlier I did receive somethings like a max stack limit warning from firebase. I know this is not a firebase problem, but I don't see any particular easy way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading a shallow tree, will download only the keys. So instead of asking the server to order and limit, you can download all keys.

Then you can order and limit it client-side, and send delete requests to Firebase in batches.

You can use this script for inspiration: https://gist.github.com/wilhuff/b78e7391396e09f6c614

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase cli tool for this: firebase database:remove --project  .

Comment: If I remember correctly then the challenge was only to delete a node and not a complete project.

Comment: @AndreasOkholm: sorry, my bad it is
remove --project <project_name> </node_name>

Comment: FYI, older  CLI versions couldn't delete large nodes, but the latest versions can.

Answer (score 0):

In Browser Console this is fastest way

`database.ref('data').limitToFirst(10000).once('value', snap => {`
    `var updates = {};`
   `snap.forEach(snap => {`
      `updates[snap.key] = null;`
 `});`
 `database.ref('data').update(updates);`
`});`