# Firebase CLI database:remove very slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I'm trying to remove a node (~100GB) in firebase using Firebase CLI
`firebase database:remove /node` and it works very slow. I cannot see any progress in the console but after 8 hours of running command, my Firebase storage amount is reduced by 5 GB only. Is there any way to efficiently remove large nodes?

Comment: This might be helpful https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/large-deletes-in-realtime-database.html

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/33946769/14945696

Comment: Those links say to do what OP is doing BTW